# Simple query with JOIN on 60M rows using index takes forever in MariaDB/MySQL

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Here's a rather simple SQL query:

```sql
select source_id
from data_sources
join sources on sources.id = data_sources.source_id
where log_time + interval sources.retention_days day < current_timestamp;
```

There are **~800 records** in `sources` and **~60 million records** in `data_sources`.

The DBMS used is Maria DB:

```
mysqld  Ver 10.3.22-MariaDB-1ubuntu1 for debian-linux-gnu on x86_64 (Ubuntu 20.04)
```

Indizes are being used apparently:

```
+--+-----------+------------+-----+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+-------+----------------------+----+-----------+
|id|select_type|table       |type |possible_keys                  |key                            |key_len|ref                   |rows|Extra      |
+--+-----------+------------+-----+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+-------+----------------------+----+-----------+
|1 |SIMPLE     |sources     |index|PRIMARY,idx_sources_1          |index_sources_on_retention_days|4      |NULL                  |757 |Using index|
|1 |SIMPLE     |data_sources|ref  |index_data_sources_on_source_id|index_data_sources_on_source_id|5      |vse_web_dev.sources.id|445 |Using where|
+--+-----------+------------+-----+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+-------+----------------------+----+-----------+
```

Surprisingly **this query takes about an hour** on an 8 core Intel i7.
RAM doesn't seem to be a problem: While the MySQL processes are causing a very high CPU load on multiple cores during execution time, there is plenty of free RAM.

Here the DDLs for the tables involved:

```sql
create table sources (
    id int auto_increment primary key,
    name varchar(255) null,
    source varchar(255) null,
    start_time varchar(255) null,
    frequency varchar(255) null,
    stop_time varchar(255) null,
    unit varchar(255) null,
    created_at datetime not null,
    updated_at datetime not null,
    type varchar(255) null,
    move_source_file tinyint(1) default 1 null,
    revision int null,
    data_freq_minute int default 1 null,
    shift_right_time_stamp tinyint(1) default 0 null,
    display_name varchar(255) null,
    source_group_id int null,
    retention_days int default 365 not null
);

create index idx_sources_1 on sources (id);
create index index_sources_on_source_group_id on sources (source_group_id);
create index index_sources_on_retention_days on sources (retention_days);

create table data_sources (
    id bigint auto_increment primary key,
    source_id int null,
    log_time datetime null,
    value float null,
    created_at datetime not null,
    updated_at datetime not null
);

create index idx_data_sources_1 on data_sources (id);
create index idx_data_sources_2 on data_sources (id, source_id, log_time);
create index index_data_sources_on_log_time on data_sources (log_time);
create index index_data_sources_on_source_id on data_sources (source_id);
create index index_data_sources_on_updated_at on data_sources (updated_at);
```

---

**Why is this taking so long and how to speed it up?**

Comment: I followed from SO, here I guess is better place to post your question, so I think the issue here, you are doing a dynamic calculation with a join on large data set, my suggestion might not be a solution but can give some hint, why not **pre-calculate** your where statement condition in a field and index it, then use it as a normal field in the query statement.

Comment: @nbk The DDL I posted was outdated and I missed it. Updated.

Comment: @ROOT Thanks for the pointer. Will try.

Comment: @ROOT Creating the pre-calculated column with an index will probably take as long as the first approach -- all in all. Of course with the benefit of improved execution time of the UPDATE. Unfortunately, `retention_days` may change often and in fast succession. So maintaining the index seems a bit unpractical in my use case.

Comment: The best apprtoach is to get rid iof the join and swtch to where in, but your logic for the time selection hinders this approach,

Comment: Aren't you likely to get a lot of duplicate `source_id` values?  If so, wouldn't you prefer to get only one copy of each that matches?  What if, for a particular `source_id`, some of the matching rows in the big table are expired, some are not?

Answer (score 1):

Adding an index to `data_sources(source_id, log_time)` solved the problem.

```sql
create index index_data_sources_source_id_log_time on data_sources(source_id, log_time);
```

This brought the execution time down to a couple of seconds.

Apparently the calculation of `interval sources.retention_days day < current_timestamp` doesn't have such a massive performance impact, as I suspected.

Thanks for the helpful comments!

Answer (score 1):

**Plan A:**

```
where log_time + interval sources.retention_days day < current_timestamp;
```

is not "sargable".  Rearrange it so that the column is on one side of an operator, then make sure there is an index (which you do):

```
WHERE data_sources.log_time <
      NOW() - INTERVAL sources.retention_days DAY
```

Also needed:

```
data_sources:  (source_id, log_time)
```

**Plan B:**

I don't have a lot of confidence in the Plan A.  So, here is another thing to try:
(working....)

[The query does not make sense; see my Comment.]

**Unrelated**

Toss two redundant indexes; you have

```
id bigint auto_increment primary key,
```

These are redundant:

```
create index idx_data_sources_1 on data_sources (id);
create index idx_data_sources_2 on data_sources (id, source_id, log_time);
```

Comment: Thanks, very appreciated. You are absolutely right in your comment, it's a bit weird to select `source_id` multiple times. What you're witnessing here is my spineless attempt to resemble the result of a legacy system -- touching downstream code in this project would surely open the gates of hell.

Comment: "gates of hell" in a legacy system.  I do understand.

Comment: MySQL defines `PRIMARY KEY` as being both an index and "clustered with the data.  Hence, those two indexes are redundant _for MySQL_.  That is, perhaps there were useful for the 'legacy' system.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I don't think they exist for a purpose. Dropped.